# Call a function in a cog using a discord button

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-buttons

I try to have a button to add ppl to the enlistment of a game. i have a function in another cog that updates the enlistment. so once someone press the button i want it to run that function it adds the person to a mySQL database and then the enlistment cog runs it and displays it on an message in the discord.

```
class reserve(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
            self.client = client

    class MyView(discord.ui.View):

        @discord.ui.button(style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, label="Enlist me")
        async def on_button_one_click(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
                enlistment = self.client.get_cog("Embed") #This part is not working
                await enlistment.enlistment(self) #This part is not working
```

This is the error I get

```
  File "f:\SeaWolf\pythonbot\cogs\reserves.py", line 31, in on_button_one_click
    enlistment = self.client.get_cog("Embed")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyView' object has no attribute 'client'
```

I can load the function from other cogs doing the same thing but with a slash command instead of a button but i wanted to make it a bit easier with a button.

Comment: Generally, don't nest classes like this in Python. It ends up having no semantic effect (other than an awkward namespace) and, in particular, does _not_ imply that the inner `self` can access the outer one. Put the two classes at the top-level, and you'll see the problem fairly quickly.

Comment: why do you have a class inside a class?